# Remote connections (RDP, AnyDesk etc) disconnect after a few seconds

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rdp

I have a user with a strange situation. We have a terminal server (Windows Server 2012 R2) where everyone can RDP in without an issue.
Except for this one person. He connects successfully, but only after a few seconds, the connection drops and the RDP client reconnects.

I changed the network cable, I tried with a USB adapter, he tried from home (via VPN), we tried using a different RDP client (Terminals) and he always has the same behavior.

The machine he is using is an HP ProBook, 1 month old, running Windows 10.

Obviously, I considered this to be an RDP issue, but today I found out that he has the same issue with AnyDesk (he works in support).

However, TeamViewer works without an issue...

I took a look through the EventViewer on the server, and there an event (Information) with the ID 9009 from Desktop Windows Manager with the content "The Desktop Window Manager has exited with code (0xd00002fe)".

Any idea what it could be?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried it from a different client machine?

Comment: Yup, his user form a different machine works just fine. Any other user on any other machine have no problem. Any user on his machine have the problem. So this must be something on this machine...

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so I think I got this figured out. It only took half a day of googleing...

I tried many solutions on a lot of forums, nothing worked.
I even uninstalled software and HP bloatware.

What eventually worked was to fix the MTU for the network adapter to 1500 (same as our network infrastructure). I did it for all adapters, including the VPN one.
You can do this via the registry or you can use a utility such as DrTCP.

If you want to know more about the optimal MTU size for you, check this out:
https://kb.netgear.com/19863/Ping-Test-to-determine-Optimal-MTU-Size-on-Router